# Split series/data frame on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas series, which I want to split into runs where the first item in each run matches a condition (maybe except the first). I can do this via `s.groupby((s==0).cumsum())`, but is there any more elegant method?

An example would be splitting `[0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 2, 7]` on `s == 0` into `[[0, 1, 3, 2], [0, 2, 8], [0], [0, 2, 7]]`.

Comment: That's pretty elegant to me.

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: Sure, added one.